# Accessing the string elements in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, indexing

I have 3 strings like the following:

```
world=["America", "Europe"]; % Parent String 
America=["USA", "Brazil", "Argentina"]; % Child1 String 
Europe=["France", "Germany", "England"]; % Child2 String
```

I want to access the elements of the child string (*Country names*) from the Parent string(*world*) and use it inside a for loop for further operation. I am trying in the following way:

```
for i=1:2
  d=world(i); % Temporary variable to store the continent name
for j=1:3
disp(d(j)); % Throws an Error: "Index exceeds Matrix dimensions
end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
My expected output is to display the country names directly from the parent string (without using the continent string)

Comment: `d` is either `"America"` or `"Europe"` as a string; not as a variable and hence cannot be indexed like a variable

Comment: d=America (When i=1, in the 1st iteration)

Comment: So what to do in the above case? Any suggestion will be a great help!

Comment: What does it mean to _access the elements of the child string (Country names) from the Parent string (world)_? What would the required output be, exactly?

Comment: @Luis: I have a hierarchy of string elements, where world is the apex and country names are at the bottom. I want to directly access the country names from the world. I want to use a country name as an individual string for further processing. This is just a fraction of my program

Comment: The honest opinion is to change your algorithm/approach.

Comment: I still don't quite get what you want, sorry. Maybe using nested structs with [dynamic field names](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) will help

Comment: @SardarUsama Still don't get it. It must be me :-)

Comment: A [map container](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) seems more appropriate than the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use variables of type **cell** to store variables of different types, in particular, strings.  I'd propose:

```
america = {'USA', 'Brazil', 'Argentina'};
europe = {'France', 'Germany', 'England', 'Italy'};
continents = {america, europe};
for i = 1 : length(continents)
  for j = 1 : length(continents{i})
    disp(continents{i}{j})
  end
end
```

If you like to index by a string rather than a positive number (i.e. numerical index), have a look at the variable type **struct**.  You can print out the list of variables in your workspace including type with the command **whos**.

Comment: The linked duplicate already suggests that

Comment: The duplicate was found after I posted this answer.  Sorry about that, I also should have searched for it.  Anyways, it's good to see that the other answer is close to mine.

Comment: The comment suggesting that a duplicate existed was written (by me) before you posted your answer. It's always good to have a quick check of the comments for the standard "`Possible duplicate of: ...`" which is automatically added beneath a question flagged accordingly. As it happens yes, this answer is suitable anyway, just for future reference.